# Not able to set a registry value in C#

Tags: c#, registry

I have a windows form app called `system_module`. And I want it to startup with windows. Here is my code for that.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string keyName = @"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName, true))
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                // Key doesn't exist.
                key.SetValue("system_module", "Application Location");
            }
            else { }
        }
    }
```

But this is not creating a value in run/
I have searched the whole registry and found nothing referring to system_module except some irrelevant values.

P.S I do not know much about registry things. Sorry if my terminology is wrong. Hope you understand what I am trying to to.
I found the above code in some other question in this site. I don't know why this is not working.

Comment: `if (key == null) { key.SetValue ... }` is a bad idea. If it doesn't exist you add it, you don't set the value of the non-existing key.

Comment: I thought Setvalue will create the key if it does not exist. Thank you very much.

Comment: It will throw a NullReferenceException instead since you can't call a method of an object that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the SetValue() - because the "Run"-Key exists

use:

```
if (key != null)
        {
            // Key doesn't exist.
            key.SetValue("system_module", "Application Location");
        }
```

and handle the key == null too to add the Run key (by default this key exists)

if you dont want to modify the key if your "system_module","Application Location" already exists you have to query the values beneath the "key"

Comment: Okay. I see now. Thanks. I have one other question. Does the setvalue() update the values if it exists?

Comment: @EmpereurAiman - Yes SetValue() updates the value! - btw: plz mark this answer as solution if it helped you